# App / Script to get extra confirmation before copying files to a folder in Windows

Tags: windows

Anyone know any app to give me an extra confirmation (would be great with a custom message) before copying / overwriting files in a directory in Windows?

I need this so i do not copy new code to a folder by misstake and it would be awesome if i had to say OK one more time and Windows show me a message like "Are you sure you want to deploy this code in production?" or something like that?

Comment: One confirmation is built into Windows, exactly how many confirmations would you like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than change the default behaviour of Windows create a script that does what you want and then you can add your own confirmations and require user to enter 'YES' when copying to a production environment.

Depolying to a production environment should be a one-step process. Otherwise you'll eventually end up forgetting something or not doing it quite right.

Comment: It's a two step operation for me. I suspect it's an even greater risk to deploy into production by mistake if it's too easy. But i get your point. I should create a sccript that do the actual copying and in that script i should choose and confirm. Good idea, thanks!